# EventStore duplicate commit exception

Tags: c#, .net, cqrs

**UPDATE:**
We are getting getting `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`. The message is:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Commits'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Commits'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated

It seems like EventStore is using streamid and commitid as unique id.

We use event store to append events as below.

```
public bool TryAppend(object[] content)
{
    if (content == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("content");

    try
    {
        using (var stream = m_storage.OpenStream(m_streamID, 0, int.MaxValue))
        {
            var versionInStore = stream.StreamRevision;

            content.ToList().ForEach(m =>
            {
                var version = ++versionInStore;
                var key = string.Format("{0}-{1:00000000}", m.GetType().Name, version);

                var savedMessage = new SavedRecord(key, version, m);

                stream.Add(new EventMessage { Body = savedMessage });
            });

            stream.CommitChanges(Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        m_logger.LogError(e);

        return false;
    }
}
```

The configuration of EventStore is as below. We are using Sql Serer 2008 as persistance store.

```
return Wireup.Init()
    .LogToOutputWindow()
        .UsingSqlPersistence(m_connectionName)
        .WithDialect(new MsSqlDialect())
        .EnlistInAmbientTransaction() // two-phase commit
    .InitializeStorageEngine()
    .UsingJsonSerialization()
        .Compress()
    .UsingSynchronousDispatchScheduler()
        .DispatchTo(new DelegateMessageDispatcher(DispatchCommit))
    .Build();
```

Any ideas why are gettin the dupplicate commit exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have got the same issue; in my case it was probably because of different threads was adding different events to the stream with same id at the same time.
Have writtent the following code to be able to retry adding events:

```
private void TryAddEvent(IStoreEvents storeEvents, IUserEvent anEvent, Guid streamId)
{
    var isCommitSuccessful = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10 && !isCommitSuccessful; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = storeEvents.OpenStream(streamId, 0, int.MaxValue))
            {
                stream.Add(new EventMessage {Body = anEvent});
                if (stream.UncommittedEvents.All(e => e.Body != anEvent))
                {
                    stream.Add(new EventMessage {Body = anEvent});
                }
                stream.CommitChanges(Guid.NewGuid());
            }
            isCommitSuccessful = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!(ex is SqlException) && !(ex is ConcurrencyException))
            {
                throw;
            }
            using (var stream = storeEvents.OpenStream(streamId, 0, int.MaxValue))
            {
                if (stream.CommittedEvents.Any(e => e.Body == anEvent))
                {
                    isCommitSuccessful = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isCommitSuccessful)
    {
        throw new ConcurrencyException(String.Format("Cannot add {0} to event store", anEvent.GetType()));
    }
}
```

Hope it would help.

Comment: Thank you Yuriy, I'll try this. To get around this, I turned to a simpler solution. I removed EventStore library and stored messages to sql server table via binary serialization. It is very similar to the Lokad CQRS event storage.